# How to write a network device driver to edit (encrypt) Network packet between sender and receiver

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver, netfilter

I try to use this [sample](https://github.com/a110605/packet_mangling) to get the network packet and I need encrypt data before reach to destinations.
like  server send a message like:  hello-world 
I need to encrypt it before reaching to server.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/skbuff.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>
#include <linux/icmp.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/inet.h>

#define DIP "1.2.3.4"

static struct nf_hook_ops nfho;     // net filter hook option struct
struct sk_buff *sock_buff;          // socket buffer used in linux kernel
struct udphdr *udp_header;          // udp header struct (not used)
struct iphdr *ip_header;            // ip header struct
struct ethhdr *mac_header;          // mac header struct


MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Redirect_Packet");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Andy Lee <a1106052000 AT gmail.com>");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

unsigned int hook_func(void *priv, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct nf_hook_state *state)
{
        sock_buff = skb;
        ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(sock_buff); //grab network header using accessor
        mac_header = (struct ethhdr *)skb_mac_header(sock_buff);

        if(!sock_buff) { return NF_DROP;}

        //TODO:: Need to edit network packet.

        if (ip_header->protocol==IPPROTO_ICMP) { //icmp=1 udp=17 tcp=6
                printk(KERN_INFO "Got ICMP Reply packet and dropped it. \n");     //log we’ve got udp packet to /var/log/messages
        printk(KERN_INFO "src_ip: %pI4 \n", &ip_header->saddr);
            printk(KERN_INFO "dst_ip: %pI4\n", &ip_header->daddr);
        ip_header->daddr = in_aton(DIP);
        printk(KERN_INFO "modified_dst_ip: %pI4\n", &ip_header->daddr);
        }
        return NF_ACCEPT;
}

int init_module()
{
        nfho.hook = hook_func;
        nfho.hooknum = 4; //NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING=0(capture ICMP Request.)  NF_IP_POST_ROUTING=4(capture ICMP reply.)
        nfho.pf = PF_INET;//IPV4 packets
        nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;//set to highest priority over all other hook functions
        nf_register_hook(&nfho); //register hook

        printk(KERN_INFO "---------------------------------------\n");
        printk(KERN_INFO "Loading dropicmp kernel module...\n");
        return 0;
}

void cleanup_module()
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning up dropicmp module.\n");
        nf_unregister_hook(&nfho);
}
```

I need to edit the packet before reach to the destination.

Comment: I would recommend that you use the newer BPF to experiment with this. You can think of it like a psuedo kernel module. It will allow you to manipulate the packet (encrypt or whatever) without having to write a full kernel module.

Comment: @LiamKelly thank you for your replying can help me mention in an example or document to do it.

Comment: Kernel documentation is below. I should warn you that it will be easier to just use IPSec programs that already exist to accomplish your goal of traffic encryption than do it yourself; however, your question asked how to do this yourself: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/filter.txt

Comment: @LiamKelly I try to do an application or driver to decrypt/decrypt the packet, I have problem with documentation because I'm still a beginner in this topic, can you suggest something or GitHub link do that thank you for helping.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like you will need to research more about TCP/IP to accomplish your goals. If you just need to encrypt data for an application read up on TLS.

Comment: Thank you for helping